# JQuery jScrollPane issue

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am trying to use `jScrollPane` on my website.

After 4 hours of searching the bug I gave up.

I really hope someone of you got a clue of this.

This is my not working page: [www.robert-richter.com](http://www.robert-richter.com)

My code:

```
<link href="../css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('.item').jScrollPane();
});
</script>

<article class="item"></article>
```

Any thought on the same will be appreciated.

Comment: can you elaborate? some specifics of whats not working, and what you are trying to achieve would be helpful

Comment: This is a working example of the jScrollPane http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

Comment: I wanted to include the vertical version of it. The script works half. It created the container but not the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your jQuery script

```
jquery(document).ready(function(){ your code here...});
```